# Primefaces calendar is not setting maxdate and mindate if using "MMM-yyyy" pattern

Tags: date, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I need your help in setting the mindate and maxdate properly in the `calendar` component in Primefaces. I am retrieving the mindate & maxdate values from a bean and everything works fine if I am using the default pattern "dd/mm/yyyy". But if I am using the pattern "MMM-yyyy", the mindate & maxdate is not set properly and will show different values other than the retrieved.

The code for mindate & maxdate:

```
    private Date maxCalendarDate = new Date();
    private Date minCalendarDate= new Date();

    public Date getMinCalendarDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(minCalendarDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
        minCalendarDate = cal.getTime();                
        return minCalendarDate;    }
}
```

And the calendar component:

```
 <p:calendar  id="popup3" value="#{bca.date4}" pattern="MMM-yyyy" mindate="#{bca.maxCalendarDate}" maxdate="#{bca.maxCalendarDate}" />
```

The maxdate instead of showing today'sDate, it will show the year 2009 and the month is October just once I am using the pattern "MMM-yyyy" in the calendar compponent.

Comment: You're using any framework for instanciate your objects?

Comment: I am using Primefaces framework

Comment: I refer to framework for instanciate your objects like to Dependency Injection. E.g. Spring or CDI.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question yet